# .NET vs HTML entities : it do a second decode?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, encoding, html-entities

Why if I wrote on a .aspx page (on .NET 3.5) :

```
<%="W&auml;hlen Sie bitte"%>
```

it prints correctly on my html page :

```
W&auml;hlen Sie bitte
```

but if I write on a .aspx.cs page somethings like :

```
mySelectBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("W&auml;hlen Sie bitte", ""));
```

(which is the same string) it prints as option on the select an uncorrectly html :

```
W&amp;auml;hlen Sie bitte
```

It does a "decode" of my string. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: The mighty power of google :), http://www.dotnetperls.com/encode-html-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET controls already HTML encode the output so you don't need to do it once again.

Simply:

```
mySelectBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("Wählen Sie bitte", ""));
```

Comment: In fact I need to print that string and put into ListItem, so my original string is W&auml;hlen Sie bitte. Tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("W&auml;hlen Sie bitte")` but I get W&#228;hlen Sie bitte...

Comment: @markzzz, why is your original string HTML encoded? That's you problem. It shouldn't be html encoded. It should be a normal string. So don't encode the normal string in the first place.

Comment: My original string become from a CMS, it is already encoded. Original string is "W&auml;hlen Sie bitte"...! But in theory, doing HtmlDecode I should get Wählen Sie bitte... but in fact it doesnt...

Comment: Opened a new thread for my specific problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035736/why-i-get-a-different-result-with-the-same-htmldecode-function

Answer (score 3):

Your first syntax is meant to output the HTML you pass in literally, so that any HTML you might include gets *rendered* instead of encoded.

The second syntax is meant to be passed the literal text you want to be displayed, though; it does the HTML encoding for you. You have over-encoded that value.