# Why I get a different result with the same HtmlDecode() function?

Tags: c#, .net, html, encoding, html-entities

This is my code :

```
string myText = "W&auml;hlen Sie bitte";
string myTextDecoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myText);
Response.Write(myTextDecoded);
ddAdulti.Items.Add(new ListItem(myTextDecoded, ""));
```

in first case (Response.Write) it prints, on my html document :

```
Wählen Sie bitte
```

which is correct! But on the select box's option it prints, on my html document :

```
W&#228;hlen Sie bitte
```

which is wrong (I've decode it...with the same function).

Why this behaviour?

Comment: on HTML! Uhm...the function HtmlDecode should be the same :O Why two different decoding? This is my question! removing it is not the solution (also because it do another encoding, and the result will be W&amp;auml;hlen Sie bitte on the select drop down option...)

Comment: I'm fairly sure you're just making an incorrect assumption here. Try assigning the result of the HtmlDecode into a variable and pass that to both Response.Write and the ListItem ctor, and you're likely to see the same result, in which case the culprit is elsewhere.

Comment: As a way of proving my point, I created a sample application and pasted your code in to the Page_Init function of a page: http://postimage.org/image/l7598yb4h/ As you can see, the result is same for both the dropdown list and the Response.Write.

Comment: Absolutly not! Check my update answer with your suggestion : the result is the same :O

Comment: It is the same on the browser page! But try to watch the HTML source...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your updated question, I'm going to make a potentially incorrect assumption about your understanding.

I'm guessing that you're looking at the HTML source and not understanding why the string is encoded in one place and unencoded in the other. The explanation is rather straightforward: *server-side controls automatically encode their content* while `Response.Write` writes raw output. There's a reason for this: server side controls often contain *user input* which is inherently *unsafe*, so it's automatically encoded to prevent [cross-site scripting attacks](http://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_site_scripting), or in the less nefarious cases, user input merely breaking your page.

By way of example, imagine if the list *didn't* encode the content and you did this:

```
ddAdulti.Items.Add(new ListItem("</select>", ""));
ddAdulti.Items.Add(new ListItem("An actual valid value", ""));
```

The net result would be that your markup would look something like this:

```
<select>
    <option></select></option>
    <option>An actual valid value</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, that's clearly broken. What you end up with depends on the interpreting browser, but is most likely an empty dropdown list.

Now, since the controls *do* encode their content, the markup ends up being:

```
<select>
    <option>&lt;/select&gt;</option>
    <option>An actual valid value</option>
</select>
```

and things work out nicely. :-)

[edit]

It occurs to me that from my example, it's probably not clear why you're seeing the behavior with a character like 'ä'. That's because many *character encodings* don't support umlauted letters, so for the control writers, it's probably easiest to simply encode all characters outside the 7-bit ASCII character set. :-)

[edit 2]

It's becoming clear to me that the original post doesn't actually describe the real problem. Apparently, what markzzz is trying to do is fetch unencoded *HTML* from the database and display it as-is for the client. There already exists a WebForms control for doing this: `LiteralControl`. It will display whatever you stick in it, unencoded.

That said, there is no way that I know to embed that inside a `DropDownList` -- see my explanation of how the rendered HTML would break. However, if you merely want to display a list of items, but not necessarily a dropdown list, you can use a `LiteralControl` inside a `Repeater` or some such.

Comment: Yeah, good answer, but for me it doesnt make any sense the encoding of an html entities. I mean : if it see that `&auml;` is ä (so it recognize htmlentities) why put it in a 7-bit ascii char?

Comment: Well, so how can I custom my encoding data? I mean, if it finds html entities, keep html entities. I don't think I can choose this option on .NET...

Comment: With "losing consistance of data" I mean that, if I have string on database with html entities, .NET convert it to 7-bit ASCII character set and than I restore/update these values on database, they will be "coded" in a different way rather than "original storing". Hope you understand what I mean? :)

Comment: +1 @AndrewBarber. The right thing to do is to store raw text in the database and then encode it on output.

Comment: @Andrew Barber : man, I need to save "html code + entities" on Database, because it is own written by user on field "Insert HTML for your script". Do you know what I mean? So it must insert "htmlentities and html tags" into this textbox! And I need to store them as they are! Is it more clear?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Chill out, communication is hard at the best of times, so we should try to keep our cool in order to not make it worse. ;-)

Comment: @markzzz Part of the problem here is that you've misrepresented your problem, because you've misunderstood it. You think your problem is with HtmlDecode, but that's not actually the case. Let me edit my answer a bit. :-)

Comment: @Andrew Barber : ok! @Rytmis : yeah, the HtmlDecode is an after-effect of the real problem, you are right. What is don't clear here is "why" .NET, understanding that `&auml;` is an htmlentities (because it understand this: on database I've saved as `&auml;`, not `ä`, and it prints `&#228;` instead of `&auml;`) it doesnt KEEP html entities, but convert them as 7-bit ASCII character set. This doesnt make sense for me (maybe because I don't see any problems with this? heehe)

Comment: This is what happens: Database produces HTML-encoded text. HtmlDecode takes it and produces plain, unencoded text. You pass that plain, unencoded text to a server-side control, which for safety reasons encodes it for display. It merely happens to encode it in a different, but equally valid way (using character entity references instead of "regular" entities).

Answer (score 3):

You can write both variants in HTML and both will work fine (as long as the document is properly encoded). Both examples will produce the same (valid) HTML and output:

```
W&#228;hlen
Wählen
```

Unencoded Umlauts are not invalid. They are equivalent to their encoded versions.

But if you don't encode them your page's encoding must support German characters. UTF-8 does.

Why do the two variants result in different HTML? Response.Write does not encode its output so you can output HTML like `"<b>x</b>"`. ListItems encode their text because you cannot output HTML in them anyway. It would make no sense to pass through unencoded text.