# Which is the server-side control to print plain-text?

Tags: .net, security, encoding, escaping

I know (thanks to a my previous SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035736/why-i-get-a-different-result-with-the-same-htmldecode-function)) that *server-side controls automatically encode their content while Response.Write (or the short version <%=%>) writes raw output*.

So, which is the server-side control, in `.NET (3.5+)`, that write encoded/escaped ("safe") plain text?

Answer (score 1):

The [Label control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) will encode what you put into it. So if you set its `Text` property to "hello my "nickname" is ", it will output HTML like `hello my &quot;nickname&quot; is &lt;markzzz&gt;`.

If you don't want ASP.NET to encode the `Text` property, use the [Literal control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx). This will output the text just like you entered it. This way, you could set its `Text` property to `<strong>something</strong>` for example. And you would get exactly that in the HTML. Your user would see **something** (so, in bold).

So, I think you want the Label control.

**Update:**

The book 'Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4' (the training kit for exam 70-515) is what got me confused. It says:

> Use the Literal control when you want to add raw HTML to a page,
>   without requiring ASP.NET to provide any additional processing. At
>   first glance, the Literal control seems very similar to the Label
>   control. However, Literal does not inherit from WebControl, as Label
>   does. Additionally, the Literal control does not add any HTML elements
>   to the webpage, whereas the Label is rendered as a  tag. This
>   means that the Literal control does not have a style property, and you
>   therefore cannot apply styles to its content.
>
> The Literal control is
>   useful when you need to add text to the output of the page dynamically
>   (from the server) but do not want to use a Label. If your text is
>   static, you can simply add it to the markup of the page (you do not
>   need a Label or a Literal control). The Literal control contains the
>   Mode property, which is used to specify any particular handling of the
>   content of the Text property. The modes available and their
>   descriptions are shown in Table 4-2.

So, I believe both can be used. The Label will just add html to the text you entered (namely, a span tag). The Literal won't, but, like bukko said, you should set the Mode property correctly.

Comment: The label control will not encode anything. The Literal control WILL encode text depending on the value of the mode attribute.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting other results than what the MSDN documentation says. My label is also encoding what I in it (in code behind). Anyway, you want either the label or the literal. Just try it out and let us know.

Comment: Interestingly - me too! Wow I was convinced about that - apologies Peter!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the question, but if you want to know which ASP controls will display text with automatic HTML encoding, I'm sure that `asp:textbox` and `asp:textarea` both do.

However, you can also achieve this with `Response.Write` as long as you encode it first, e.g.

```
Response.Write( Server.HTMLEncode("The <select /> control!") );
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx for more info.

Or, with .NET 4, you can use the old classic ASP nuggets for encoded output:

```
<% string output_text = "<select />"; %>
<%= output_text %>
```

Is this more what you wanted?

Comment: No! Suppose I have text from DB, like `hello my "nickname" is <markzzz>` and I'd like to print it encoded... is there a server-side control that manage plain-text? For example `<asp:DropDownList>` is a server-side control that manage drop down list :)

Comment: Ah sorry - that is the Literal control. You can apply encoding or not, as you want to. Example here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_literal.asp